# What are the tell-tale signs of bad object oriented design?

Tags: oop

When designing a new system or getting your head around someone else's code, what are some tell tale signs that something has gone wrong in the design phase? Are there clues to look for on class diagrams and inheritance hierarchies or even in the code itself that just scream for a design overhaul, particularly early in a project?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The things that mostly stick out for me are "[code smells](http://www.soberit.hut.fi/mmantyla/BadCodeSmellsTaxonomy.htm)".

Mostly I'm sensitive to things that go against "good practice".

Things like:

- Methods that do things other than what you'd think from the name (eg: FileExists() that silently deletes zero byte files)
- A few extremely long methods (sign of an object wrapper around a procedure)
- Repeated use of switch/case statements on the same enumerated member (sign of sub-classes needing extraction)
- Lots of member variables that are used for processing, not to capture state (might indicate need to extract a method object)
- A class that has lots of responsibilities (violation of Single Repsonsibility principle)
- Long chains of member access (this.that is fine, this.that.theOther is fine, but my.very.long.chain.of.member.accesses.for.a.result is brittle)
- Poor naming of classes
- Use of too many design patterns in a small space
- Working too hard (rewriting functions already present in the framework, or elsewhere in the same project)
- Poor spelling (anywhere) and grammar (in comments), or comments that are simply misleading

Comment: Nice list, +1. I'm however curious about the excessive design pattern density. Have you really encounter that ? I'd say it's more when patterns are mis-used and abused.

Answer (score 20):

I'd say the number one rule of poor OO design (and yes I've been guilty of it too many times!) is:

- Classes that break the **Single
  Responsibility Principle (SRP**) and
  perform too many actions

Followed by:

- Too much inheritance instead of
  composition, i.e. Classes that
  derive from a sub-type purely so
  they get functionality for free.
  **Favour Composition over Inheritance**.

Comment: True. Would like to include a couple of more, Programming to an Interface, and Seperation of Concerns.

Answer (score 19):

Impossible to unit test properly.

Comment: Bingo! See my comment. The worst part is that at least 90% of the code you'll ever see is impossible to unit test properly.

Comment: I believe this is the same thing as saying "high coupling".

Answer (score 15):

[**Anti-patterns**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern)

**Software design anti-patterns**

- Abstraction inversion : Not exposing implemented functionality required by users, so that they re-implement it using higher level functions
- Ambiguous viewpoint: Presenting a model (usually OOAD) without specifying its viewpoint
- Big ball of mud: A system with no recognizable structure
- Blob: Generalization of God object from object-oriented design
- Gas factory: An unnecessarily complex design
- Input kludge: Failing to specify and implement handling of possibly invalid input
- Interface bloat: Making an interface so powerful that it is extremely difficult to implement
- Magic pushbutton: Coding implementation logic directly within interface code, without using abstraction.
- Race hazard: Failing to see the consequence of different orders of events
- Railroaded solution: A proposed solution that while poor, is the only one available due to poor foresight and inflexibility in other areas of the design
- Re-coupling: Introducing unnecessary object dependency
- Stovepipe system: A barely maintainable assemblage of ill-related components
- Staralised schema: A database schema containing dual purpose tables for normalised and datamart use

**Object-oriented design anti-patterns**

- Anemic Domain Model: The use of domain model without any business logic which is not OOP because each object should have both attributes and behaviors
- BaseBean: Inheriting functionality from a utility class rather than delegating to it
- Call super: Requiring subclasses to call a superclass's overridden method
- Circle-ellipse problem: Subtyping variable-types on the basis of value-subtypes
- Empty subclass failure: Creating a class that fails the "Empty Subclass Test" by behaving differently from a class derived from it without modifications
- God object: Concentrating too many functions in a single part of the design (class)
- Object cesspool: Reusing objects whose state does not conform to the (possibly implicit) contract for re-use
- Object orgy: Failing to properly encapsulate objects permitting unrestricted access to their internals
- Poltergeists: Objects whose sole purpose is to pass information to another object
- Sequential coupling: A class that requires its methods to be called in a particular order
- Singletonitis: The overuse of the singleton pattern
- Yet Another Useless Layer: Adding unnecessary layers to a program, library or framework. This became popular after the first book on programming patterns.
- Yo-yo problem: A structure (e.g., of inheritance) that is hard to understand due to excessive fragmentation

Comment: What is the particular issue with a poltergeist? Extracting information in a certain way seems a job not for the access but the holder of that information.

Comment: @ThomasE Initialising and releasing short lived objects is a waste of resource, and a sign of a poor OO design, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poltergeist_(computer_programming)

Answer (score 9):

This question makes the assumption that object-oriented means good design.  There are cases where another approach is much more appropriate.

Comment: +1, although I would say "another approach" rather than "functional approach".  There are very few design approaches which do not have at least a small class of problems for which they are the most appropriate choice.

Answer (score 7):

One smell is objects having hard dependencies/references to other objects that aren't a part of their natural object hierarchy or domain related composition.

Example: Say you have a city simulation. If the a Person object has a NearestPostOffice property you are probably in trouble.

Answer (score 4):

One thing I hate to see is a base class down-casting itself to a derived class.  When you see this, you know you have problems.

Other examples might be:

- Excessive use of switch statements
- Derived classes that override everything

Comment: "a base class down-casting itself to a derived class" - as always there's an exception, which when you use CRTP to implement simulated dynamic binding in C++. The derived class is supplied to the base class as a template parameter, so you absolutely definitely know the cast is valid.

Comment: That is very different than what I am talking about.  I am talking about when a Vehicle class knows that the Car class exists.  In your case, the base class still has no knowledge of the derived class.  Like you said, exceptions to rules.  I wouldn't even call them rules... warning smells, perhaps?

Comment: Well, the base *class* does have specific knowledge of the derived class, it's just that the programmer only deals directly with the base *class template*, which doesn't. C++ is pure gold for pedants ;-)

Answer (score 4):

In my view, all OOP code degenerates to procedural code over a sufficiently long time span.

Granted, if you read my most recent question, you might understand why I am a little jaded.

The key problem with OOP is that it doesn't make it obvious that your object construction graph should be independent of your call graph.

Once you fix that problem, OOP actually starts to make sense. The problem is that very few teams are aware of this design pattern.

Comment: Hi, I do not understand. Could You provide example, please. Thanks.

Comment: An answer that makes me to think deeper about. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a few:

- Circular dependencies
- You with property XYZ of a base class wasn't protected/private
- You wish your language supported multiple inheritance

Comment: I have to disagree with the third one.  Sometimes, MI can be a good thing if used properly.

Answer (score 2):

Within a long method, sections surrounded with #region / #endregion - in almost every case I've seen, that code could easily be extracted into a new method OR needed to be refactored in some way.

Overly-complicated inheritance trees, where the sub-classes do very different things and are only tangentially related to one another.

Violation of DRY - sub-classes that each override a base method in almost exactly the same way, with only a minor variation.  An example:  I recently worked on some code where the subclasses each overrode a base method and where the only difference was a type test ("x is ThisType" vs "x is ThatType").  I implemented a method in the base that took a generic type T, that it then used in the test.  Each child could then call the base implementation, passing the type it wanted to test against.  This trimmed about 30 lines of code from each of 8 different child classes.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate code = Code that does the same thing...I think in my experience this is the biggest mistake that can occur in OO design.

Comment: Duplicate code is not bad if it does the same thing but for different reasons.  Over zealous application of DRY can lead to unnecessary coupling of functionality across class or domain boundaries.  Just because A does f and B does f and A.f and B.f do the same thing, doesn't mean you need to create an F.f  that takes an A or a B, just so you don't duplicate code...especially later when you add D.f and when B.f needs to be refactored.

Answer (score 1):

Objects are good create a gazillion of them is a bad OO design.

Answer (score 0):

Having all you objects inherit some base utility class just so you can call your utility methods without having to type so much code.

Answer (score 0):

Find a programmer who is experienced with the code base.  Ask them to explain how something works.

If they say "this function calls that function", their code is procedural.

If they say "this class interacts with that class", their code is OO.

Comment: What if both classes are singletons =)

Comment: I mean "if they describe their code as the relationships between classes, it's OO; as the relationships between methods, it's procedural; as the relationships between statements, it's spagetti"

Comment: The class should not perform the interaction itself. What you've said is cool, sounds well but somewhat loose.

Answer (score 0):

Following are most prominent features of a bad design:

1. Rigidity
2. Fragility
3. Immobility

Take a look at [The Dependency Inversion Principle](http://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2009/01/30/the-dependency-inversion-principle/)

Answer (score 0):

When you don't just have a Money\Amount class but a TrainerPrice class, TablePrice class, AddTablePriceAction class and so on.

IDE Driven Development or Auto-Complete development. Combined with extreme strict typing is a perfect storm.

This is where you see what could be a lot of what could be variable values become class names and method names as well as the gratuitous use of classes in general. You'll also see things like all primitives becoming objects. All literals as classes. Function parameters as classes. Then conversion methods everywhere. You'll also see things like a class wrapping another delivering a subset of methods to another class inclusive of only the ones it needs at present.

This creates the possibility to generate an near infinite amount of code which is great if you have billable hours. When variables, contexts, properties and states get unrolled into hyper explicit and overly specific classes then this creates an exponential cataclysm as sooner or later those things multiply. Think of it like [a, b] x [x, y]. This can be further compounded by an attempt to create a full fluent interface as well as adhere to as many design patterns as possible.

OOP languages are not as polymorphic as some loosely typed languages. Loosely typed languages often offer runtime polymorphism in shallow syntax that static analysis can't handle.

In OOP you might see forms of repetition hard to automatically detect that could be turned into more dynamic code using maps. Although such languages are less dynamic you can achieve dynamic features with some extra-work.

The trade of here is that you save thousands (or millions) of lines of code while potentially loosing IDE features and static analysis. Performance can go either way. Run time polymorphism can often be converted to generated code. However in some cases the space is so huge that anything other than runtime polymorphism is impossible.

Problems are a lot more common with OOP languages lacking generics and when OOP programmers try to strictly type dynamic loosely typed language.

What happens without generics is where you should have A for X = [Q, W, E] and Y = [R, T, Y] you instead see [AQR, AQT, AQY, AWR, AWT, AWY, AER, AET, AEY]. This is often due to fear or using typeless or passing the type as a variable for loosing IDE support.

Traditionally loosely typed languages are made with a text editor rather than an IDE and the advantage lost through IDE support is often gained in other ways such as organising and structuring code such that it is navigable.

Often IDEs can be configured to understand your dynamic code (and link into it) but few properly support it in a convenient manner.

Hint: The context here is OOP gone horrifically wrong in PHP where people using simple OOP Java programming traditionally have tried to apply that to PHP which even with some OOP support is a fundamentally different type of language.

Designing against your platform to try to turn it into one your used to, designing to cater to an IDE or other tools, designing to cater to supporting Unit Tests, etc should all ring alarm bells because it's a significant deviation away from designing working software to solve a given category of problems or a given feature set.